# Nifi Cluster on docker is not starting up, Working only on one Node

Tags: apache, docker, apache-nifi

I am trying to install Apache Nifi on docker cluster with two Agents, Single Node cluster is working while starting on Second Node I am getting below Error

My stack trace

```
2017-09-13 06:00:52,640 INFO [main] o.a.n.admin.AuditDataSourceFactoryBean Database not built for repository: jdbc:h2:./database_repository/nifi-flow-audit;AUTOCOMMIT=OFF;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_MODE=3;LOCK_TIMEOUT=25000;WRITE_DELAY=0;AUTO_SERVER=FALSE.  Building now...
2017-09-13 06:00:52,794 WARN [main] org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@28dd038f{/nifi-api,file:///opt/nifi/work/jetty/nifi-web-api-1.3.0.war/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.3.0.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-api-1.3.0.war}
org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to start Flow Controller.
        at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:88)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:876)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:532)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:839)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1480)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1442)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:799)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:290)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:705)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:160)
        at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:267)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowService': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowController' defined in class path resource [nifi-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'clusterCoordinator' while setting bean property 'clusterCoordinator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clusterCoordinator': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clusterCoordinationProtocolSenderListener' defined in class path resource [nifi-cluster-protocol-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'protocolListener' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'protocolListener' defined in class path resource [nifi-cluster-protocol-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [int]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [null] to required type [int]: Failed to convert value of type [null] to required type [int]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [null] to required type [int]: PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [null]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
```

Comment: post details on how you are running the cluster

Answer (score 3):

The error you are getting is showing that it cannot instantiate a spring bean 'protocolListener' defined in class path resource [nifi-cluster-protocol-context.xml].

That bean definition looks like this:

```
<!-- protocol listener -->
    <bean id="protocolListener" class="org.apache.nifi.cluster.protocol.impl.SocketProtocolListener">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <bean factory-bean="nifiProperties" factory-method="getClusterNodeProtocolThreads"/>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="1">
            <bean factory-bean="nifiProperties" factory-method="getClusterNodeProtocolPort"/>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg ref="protocolServerSocketConfiguration" index="2"/>
        <constructor-arg ref="protocolContext" index="3"/>
    </bean>
```

The error message also says the issue is with index 1 which is for getClusterNodeProtocolPort.

You most likely have not set nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port in nifi.properties for this node.